# PHP Router Can't get the variable from the parsed url

Tags: php, .htaccess, router

I have found a PHP Router library and I have a problem with it. If I try to get the parameter from the url, it won't return the value. The other issue is when I want to route to a .php file in a folder, it throws a 404 error.

I have the root folder, which contains the index.php and the .htaccess files, and a folder that contains the user.php file. If I want to open the `localhost/user/3` it should route to the `/views/user.php`, but I get the 404 error. But if I move the `user.php` to the root folder, I won't get the 404 error, but I can't get the `id which is 3`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[The repository of this project](https://github.com/yousufnoor5/php-basic-routing)

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`index.php`

```
class Route {
private function simpleRoute($file, $route){
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['uri'])){
        $route = preg_replace("/(^\/)|(\/$)/","",$route);
        $reqUri =  preg_replace("/(^\/)|(\/$)/","",$_REQUEST['uri']);
    }else { $reqUri = "/"; }

    if($reqUri == $route){
        $params = [];
        include($file);
        exit();

    }

}

function add($route,$file){

    //will store all the parameters value in this array
    $params = [];

    //will store all the parameters names in this array
    $paramKey = [];

    //finding if there is any {?} parameter in $route
    preg_match_all("/(?<={).+?(?=})/", $route, $paramMatches);

    //if the route does not contain any param call simpleRoute();
    if(empty($paramMatches[0])){
        $this->simpleRoute($file,$route);
        return;
    }

    //setting parameters names
    foreach($paramMatches[0] as $key){
        $paramKey[] = $key;
    }

    //replacing first and last slashes
    //$_REQUEST['uri'] will be empty if req uri is /
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['uri'])){
        $route = preg_replace("/(^\/)|(\/$)/","",$route);
        $reqUri =  preg_replace("/(^\/)|(\/$)/","",$_REQUEST['uri']);
    }else{
        $reqUri = "/";
    }

    //exploding route address
    $uri = explode("/", $route);

    //will store index number where {?} parameter is required in the $route 
    $indexNum = []; 

    //storing index number, where {?} parameter is required with the help of regex
    foreach($uri as $index => $param){
        if(preg_match("/{.*}/", $param)){
            $indexNum[] = $index;
        }
    }

    //exploding request uri string to array to get
    //the exact index number value of parameter from $_REQUEST['uri']
    $reqUri = explode("/", $reqUri);

    //running for each loop to set the exact index number with reg expression
    //this will help in matching route
    foreach($indexNum as $key => $index){
    
         //in case if req uri with param index is empty then return
        //because url is not valid for this route
        if(empty($reqUri[$index])){
            return;
        }
        
        //setting params with params names
        $params[$paramKey[$key]] = $reqUri[$index];


        //this is to create a regex for comparing route address
        $reqUri[$index] = "{.*}";
    }

    //converting array to sting
    $reqUri = implode("/",$reqUri);

    //replace all / with \/ for reg expression
    //regex to match route is ready !
    $reqUri = str_replace("/", '\\/', $reqUri);

    //now matching route with regex
    if(preg_match("/$reqUri/", $route))
    {
        include($file);
        exit();

    }
}

function notFound($file){
    include($file);
    exit();
}
}
 $route = new Route();
 $route->add("/user/{id}","views/user.php");
 $route->notFound("404.php");
```

`views/user.php`

```
echo $params['id'];
```

Comment: Please format your code. This is no fun to read.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$route->add("/user/{id}","views/user.php");`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yeah it should, updated the post.

Comment: Lots of existing router implementations out there.  What have you done to debug?  Hard to expect strangers to look through an entire class and detect a problem.

Comment: Every time that `add()` performs a `return` for a non-match, add some code to dump those variables so you can see what's going on.